# Python -c switch

Tags: python, bash, shell, quoting

I currently have

```
".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16) for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?!$)', r'\1.', "00112233")).split('.')])
'xx.xx.xx.xx'
```

which works but when i try to use it via the python -c switch it fails ?

```
[root@monty ~]# python -c "import re ; ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16) for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?!$)', r'\1.', "00112233")).split('.')])"
python -c "import re ; ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16) for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?"import re ; ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16) for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?python)', r'\1.', "00112233")).split('.')])")', r'\1.', "00112233")).split('.')])"
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `str'
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Unescaped double quotes inside of double quotes..

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a quoting issue on the command line.

Try wrapping the Python string in single quotes instead, and not using single quotes inside it.

You can also escape the quotes that collide with the shell's interpretation, using `\"`.

```
$ python -c 'import re;print ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16) for x in (re.sub(r"(.{2})(?!$)", r"\1.", "00112233")).split(".")])'
0.17.34.51
```

Note: as your not running the python interpretor any more you need to explicitly print the results.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Yes, but those can be changed to double quotes, there's no difference in Python unless they're used to nest which they don't seem to be.

Comment: still issues when trying that method :-(

Answer (score 7):

Feed your script in on a quoted heredoc instead of using `python -c`, and you make the problem moot in its entirety; also, this lets you use newlines in your code, so it can be much more readable.

```
python - <<'EOF'
import re
print ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16)
                                for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?!$)',
                                          r'\1.',
                                          "00112233")).split('.')])
EOF
```

Note that it's essential that you use `<<'EOF'` rather than `<<EOF` here; the former prevents the shell from trying to expand the heredoc's contents.

---

If you *really* want to use `python -c`, that's approach can still benefit from a heredoc used to capture the script into a variable:

```
python_script=$(cat <<'EOF'
import re
print ".".join(str(z) for z in [int(x, 16)
                                for x in (re.sub(r'(.{2})(?!$)',
                                          r'\1.',
                                          "00112233")).split('.')])
EOF
)

python -c "$python_script"
```